# loading gis map to offline anylogic computer

Tags: anylogic

i'm using anylogic in an offline environment that cannot be connected to the internet.

in my laptop i can use the Anylogic GIS maps placing agents and using it to calculate distances etc.
is there a way to download a specific (or not specific ) gis map and then load it into Anylogic ?

and also - will it have functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Run the model from a non-offline environment and make it us *all* GIS features that you need, i.e. display all areas, zooms...

The model will cache the data locally in a subfolder.

If you copy that into your offline model's folder, the model will work as if it would be online.

Obvious caveat: you must make sure to force-cache everything you need from the GIS map when online

Comment: meaning obviously thay i need to place all gis points prior to copying the model ?

Comment: probably, give it a simple test run first before going full production mode :)